# EPPlus always returns Null when using reading with Linq

Tags: c#, epplus

Using .NET Core, I've followed the EPPlus docs ([here](https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus.Sample.NetCore/blob/master/10-ReadDataUsingLinq/ReadDataUsingLinq.cs)) but always get a null. My goal is to read text but just for example, I was also testing with a double (percentage value in Excel). When I do this:

```
var myval = myWorksheet.Cells["B21"].Value;
```

I get this: .55

When I do this:

```
var query1 = (from cell in myWorksheet.Cells["B21"] where cell.Value is double && (double)cell.Value >= .33 && (double)cell.Value <= 10000 select cell);
```

I get null. I've tried many variations and read everything I could on stackoverflow and nothing's helped.

I really want text and this is what I used (also returns nothing, I just get 0) and there is definitely the search value in A21:

```
var searchCell = from cell in myWorksheet.Cells["A20:A33"]
where cell.Value != null && cell.Value.ToString() == "Stuff" && cell.Start != null
select cell.Start.Row;
```

Comment: Well your queries aren't identical, but have you verified, that your decimal seperator works / is correct? In my case it's a comma, and it will not accept it as double if I have a cell with `21.5` instead of `21,5`.

Comment: What does `var query1 = (from cell in myWorksheet.Cells["B21"] where cell.Value is double select cell.Value);` give you?

Comment: @Marco yes that was intentional as I was experimenting. Yes my comma separator is period. I'm actually less interested in the double than the text, but seems like it should populate with a value.

Comment: @AstridE. -the query shows Current property as null and searchCell's Current shows as 0.